# Does the funcitonal equation of the zeta function apply for all reals?

Tags: riemann-zeta

If I plug in 4 for s into:

$$\begin{equation}
\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\Gamma(1-s)\sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\zeta(1-s).
\end{equation}$$

Doesn't $$\zeta(4) = 0
$$
because of the sine function?

Does this mean that the above functional equation has parameters for where it can be used?

Comment: Perhaps you missed the pole of $\Gamma(1-s)$ when $s = 4$.

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^4} = 0$?  I hope not.

Comment: It's way more involved than what you think. As already commented, the gamma function has singularities at the negative integers, which together with the zero of of the sine function *and* all the rest gives you $\;\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}\;$ ...but it is not trivial to get to this vale.