# Why doesn't the functional equation imply that $\zeta(s)=0$ for positive even integers?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

The Riemann Zeta Function satisfies the functional equation $\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$. But when $s$ is a positive even number, $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi s}{2}\right)$ and $\Gamma(1-s)$ are both $0$, which would imply that $\zeta(2)=0$, but of course, $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$. What am I missing?

Comment: I asked a similar question here/ the third comment helped: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606321/does-the-funcitonal-equation-of-the-zeta-function-apply-for-all-reals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Gamma$ has a pole, not a zero, at each negative integer.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Does the product of the sine and the gamma functions "cancel" to some other function at the even integers?

Comment: @Nishant : $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)\sin(\pi s ) = \pi$.

Comment: Yes: $\Gamma(s)$ has a simple pole at $s = -n$.

Comment: Wait, but the sine has a factor of $1/2$ in it...